# If Else & Switch statements do not work with values from HTML form (made interactive with JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, widget, radio-button

I am creating a widget where a user selects an option from some radio buttons and a response to the user is created by JavascriptCoding (the response differs depending on which option the user has picked). I can get the widget to display which option the user has picked in a sentence ("You have selected "something", here are your recommendations:").

However, after this line I want to create a statement that actually gives the user recommendations (the widget's concept is: user chooses a university degree from the options, program gives them back recommended subjects related to the degree).

Every time I tried an If/else statement or a "switch" statement, nothing happens as I test the widget (doesn't even show the "you have chosen..." part). I have included my last attempt. If the switch statement is deleted, the first part of the response works, if it is included, nothing happens when you press "Submit!"

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script language="JavaScript">
   var degreeChoice = (form.degree.value)
    function processDegrees (form) {
      var degreeChoice = (form.degree.value);
            document.write ("You chose" + " " + degreeChoice + ", here are your reccomendations:" + " ")
   };

    switch(degreeChoice) {
case "agriculture":
        document.write("It works");
        [break;]
case "arts":
            document.write("still works");
            [break;]
default:
        document.write("An error has occurred");
        [break;]
}

</script>       

    <body>
<form name="chooseDegrees" action=" " method="get">
    <h1>Choose Degrees:</h1>
  <input type="radio" name="degree" value="agriculture"> Agriculture
<br>
  <input type="radio" name="degree" value="arts"> Arts
<br> 
  <input type="radio" name="degree" value="biomedicine"> Biomedicine
<br>
  <input type="radio" name="degree" value="commerce"> Commerce
<br>
  <input type="radio" name="degree" value="environments"> Environments
<br>
  <input type="radio" name="degree" value="fine arts"> Fine Arts
<br>
  <input type="radio" name="degree" value="music"> Music
<br>
  <input type="radio" name="degree" value="oral health"> Oral Health
<br>
  <input type="radio" name="degree" value="science"> Science
<br><br> 
<input type="submit"value="Submit!" onclick="processDegrees(this.form)">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [break;] is causing a syntax error - check the browsers console as any error has a tendency to stop all JavaScript execution. (press the F12 key thne select the console tab to see any errors). Change [break;] to break; (remove the square brackets).

Comment: Thanks for the response, the tutorial I looked at must have been wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You cannot use document.write after load - it will wipe the page
2. You cannot use submit and expect to stay on the page. I moved it to the onsubmit of the form and return false to not submit
3. You have [break] instead of just break
4. There was a `var degreeChoice = (form.degree.value);` outside the function
5. The function ended before the switch with the `};`

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script language="JavaScript">
  function processDegrees (form) {
    var degreeChoice = (form.degree.value);
    text="You chose " + degreeChoice + ", here are your recommendations: ";

    switch(degreeChoice) {
      case "agriculture":
        text += "It works";
        break;
      case "arts":
        text +="still works";
        break;
      default:
        text+="An error has occurred";
        break;
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=text;
    return false; // cancel submission
  }
</script>       

    <body>
<form name="chooseDegrees" action=" " method="get" onsubmit="return processDegrees(this)">
    <h1>Choose Degrees:</h1>
  <input type="radio" name="degree" value="agriculture"> Agriculture
<br>
  <input type="radio" name="degree" value="arts"> Arts
<br> 
  <input type="radio" name="degree" value="biomedicine"> Biomedicine
<br>
  <input type="radio" name="degree" value="commerce"> Commerce
<br>
  <input type="radio" name="degree" value="environments"> Environments
<br>
  <input type="radio" name="degree" value="fine arts"> Fine Arts
<br>
  <input type="radio" name="degree" value="music"> Music
<br>
  <input type="radio" name="degree" value="oral health"> Oral Health
<br>
  <input type="radio" name="degree" value="science"> Science
<br><br> 
<input type="submit "value="Submit!">
</form> 
<div id="result"></div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Example

```js
 function processDegrees(form) {
   var degreeChoice = (form.degree.value);
   text = "You chose " + degreeChoice + ", here are your recommendations: ";
 switch (degreeChoice) {
   case "agriculture":
     text += "It works";
     break;
   case "arts":
     text += "still works";
     break;
   default:
     text += "An error has occurred";
     break;
 }
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = text;
 return false; // cancel submission
 }
```

```html
<form name="chooseDegrees" action=" " method="get" onsubmit="return processDegrees(this)">
  <h1>Choose Degrees:</h1>
  <input type="radio" name="degree" value="agriculture">Agriculture
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="degree" value="arts">Arts
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="degree" value="biomedicine">Biomedicine
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="degree" value="commerce">Commerce
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="degree" value="environments">Environments
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="degree" value="fine arts">Fine Arts
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="degree" value="music">Music
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="degree" value="oral health">Oral Health
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="degree" value="science">Science
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: You are welcome. I hope it will not be too obvious you had a little help.

Comment: I also removed an unnecessary `" "+` and added space to the strings